# Application freezes when I open a file dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I want it so that when the user clicks on the button and opens an image, the image gets copied to another location and the filepath of the copied image is saved inside 'Properties.Settings.Default.custombgfilepath'
Here is my code:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check for openfile dialog result
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            //initialize destination
            string destination = @"C:\Launchicity\";
            //Get filename
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            //get filepath
            string filepath = destination + filename;
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, filepath);
                Properties.Settings.Default.custombgfilepath = filepath;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.custombgfilepath = filepath;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the Windows Form Designer auto genertaed code for openfiledialog1:

```
    // 
    // openFileDialog1
    // 
        this.openFileDialog1.Filter = "\"PNG (*.png)|*.png|JPG (*.jpg)|*.jpg\"";
        this.openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Image";
        this.openFileDialog1.FileOk += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(this.OpenFileDialog1_FileOk);
```

When I click on the button however, the application freezes.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Does the dialog show? The application is *supposed* to freeze as long as the dialog is shown.

Comment: It might be a good idea to debug the application and see if any error is thrown.

Comment: FYI look into Path.Combine() for building a path from folder and file

Comment: @theblackips the dialog does not show. The application just freezes.

Comment: @Apollo199999999 Can we see some of the dialog's code then?

Comment: @theblackips what do you mean? The code is in the post.

Comment: I mean the designer code of openFileDialog1

Comment: @theblackips I edited the post to include the designer code of open file dialog 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More questions talk to me. Pls send me feedback ;) try this:

(Edited)

```
using system.IO   
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //check for openfile dialog result
            this.openFileDialog1.Filter = "\"PNG (*.png)|*.png|JPG (*.jpg)|*.jpg\"";
            this.openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Image";
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            //initialize destination
            string destination = @"C:\Launchicity\";
            //Get filename
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            //get filepath
            string filepath = destination + filename;
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, filepath);
                //Properties.Settings.Default.custombgfilepath = filepath; i dont have custombgfilepath
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                //Properties.Settings.Default.custombgfilepath = filepath; i dont have custombgfilepath
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Works! Thank you